# Visual Studio 2013 Stopping debugger, will forcibly close all open files

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Assume I have few CS files open, and then start debugging, and stop debugging.
Stopping debugger, will forcibly close all open files. IDE will not open these files, until i Close & ReOpen the SLN file.

Steps to reproduce problem

1) Open the solution

2) Open one or two CS file in viewer

3) Say EFF-FIVE to debug.

4) Terminate the debugger

5) Now both both files will also get closed.
   From now on wards, IDE will not open those files, even 'View Code' fails.
   If you try to debug(by pressing EFF-FIVE), debugger complains that source-file is 
   missing.

6) To reinstate normalcy, I have to close-solution and reopen it. Then those 2 files will open.

7) This happens to every solution on this machine, so problem is not "SLN specific".

I have tried REPAIR & Uninstall/Install without any +ve result. I am planning to format the machine, reinstall OS and VS.

Is there is any subtle solution for this problem?

Comment: Ensure that the files are local to your machine, they are not opened by another version of VS IDE and that the application exe is not running. Check you Windows tasks menu and make sure that there is no other instance of VS or any other program using the solution. Make sure the project config is 'Debug'. Make sure you have no compilation errors. I don't think that re-installing windows is going to solve this.

Comment: NoChance - I have taken care of all of the your suggestions.